# test failure:io error: the network adapter could not estailish the connection in sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql

i got a error - test failure:io error: the network adapter could not estailish the connection while i am creating database in oracle sql developer. Please tell me any solution to fix it.

Comment: are you creating a database or are you creating a database connection?

Comment: I'm creating database.

Comment: then you should be using sqlplus, or using the database creation assistant, DBCA. We also need more help in order to help you. have you actually created the database yet?

Comment: No, database is not creating. It shows io error every time.

Comment: I have installed only sql developer on my machine right now. Is there any need to install oracle 11g or it's enough???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a database to connect to.

Oracle SQL Developer is just the client. You need a server too.

Some ideas on how to quickly get one of those database things [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).